# How do I change this code to use File I/O to Save a "High Score" File for my Game

Tags: ruby, file-io

I am now using YAML to store the data and it works in creating and storing the file. I am still trying to figure out how to get the table to print to the terminal in the correct format using the text-table gem. Here is the code:

```
def highscore
if File.exists?('highscore.txt')
    hs = YAML.load_file("highscore.txt")
else
    hs = {
        1 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        2 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        3 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        4 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        5 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        6 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        7 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        8 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        9 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        10 => { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
        }
end

(1..10).each do |rank|
  t = Time.now
  if @grand_total > hs[rank][:score]
    hs[rank][:score] = @grand_total
    hs[rank][:date] = "#{t.month}/#{t.day}/#{t.year}" 
    puts "Congratulations you set a new HIGH SCORE! Enter your initials."
    initials = gets.chomp.upcase
    hs[rank][:player] = initials
    break
  else
    puts "Sorry, you didn't get a high score. Try again!"
  end
end

File.write('highscore.txt', hs.to_yaml)

puts hs.to_table
end
```

Comment: I don't see any place in your code where you tried to save, or showed where you want to save.

Comment: The code I have above doesn't save the high score table besides for the current session. I was asking what the best way of saving it to a file, and then reading it back in every time a new session begins would be, this way a single user or multiple users on a single computer could keep track of their best scores.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you look into using the [YAML](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) data serializer. It creates a nicely formatted and readable file that is easily read by other languages.

```
require 'pp'
require 'yaml'

hs = [["RANK", "PLAYER", "SCORE", "DATE"],
      ["1st", "-", 0, "-"],
      ["2nd", "-", 0, "-"],
      ["3rd", "-", 0, "-"],
      ["4th", "-", 0, "-"],
      ["5th", "-", 0, "-"],
      ["6th", "-", 0, "-"],
      ["7th", "-", 0, "-"],
      ["8th", "-", 0, "-"],
      ["9th", "-", 0, "-"],
      ["10th", "-", 0, "-"]]

puts hs.to_yaml
```

Which looks like:

```
---
- - RANK
  - PLAYER
  - SCORE
  - DATE
- - 1st
  - '-'
  - 0
  - '-'
- - 2nd
  - '-'
  - 0
  - '-'
- - 3rd
  - '-'
  - 0
  - '-'
- - 4th
  - '-'
  - 0
  - '-'
- - 5th
  - '-'
  - 0
  - '-'
- - 6th
  - '-'
  - 0
  - '-'
- - 7th
  - '-'
  - 0
  - '-'
- - 8th
  - '-'
  - 0
  - '-'
- - 9th
  - '-'
  - 0
  - '-'
- - 10th
  - '-'
  - 0
  - '-'
```

Saving to file is easy:

```
File.write('path/to/file.yaml', hs.to_yaml)
```

And reading it back in is as easy:

```
hs = YAML.load_file('path/to/file.yaml')
```

Read through the "[Yaml Cookbook](http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html)" for more information how Ruby and YAML structures are related.

That said, I'd recommend a different data structure for your high score table. Instead of arrays of arrays, which are a pain to access, use a hash of hashes:

```
hs = {
  1 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
  2 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
  3 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
  4 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
  5 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
  6 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
  7 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
  8 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
  9 =>  { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
  10 => { player: '', score: 0, date: '' },
}
```

This will make the YAML file easier to understand:

```
---
1:
  :player: ''
  :score: 0
  :date: ''
2:
  :player: ''
  :score: 0
  :date: ''
3:
  :player: ''
  :score: 0
  :date: ''
4:
  :player: ''
  :score: 0
  :date: ''
5:
  :player: ''
  :score: 0
  :date: ''
6:
  :player: ''
  :score: 0
  :date: ''
7:
  :player: ''
  :score: 0
  :date: ''
8:
  :player: ''
  :score: 0
  :date: ''
9:
  :player: ''
  :score: 0
  :date: ''
10:
  :player: ''
  :score: 0
  :date: ''
```

And will simplify your accesses to the table in your code.

In general, your code needs a major clean up. A very strong principle in writing code is "DRY" AKA "Don't repeat yourself". You have a huge amount of redundancy in your code, that can be simplified greatly. That needs to be handled in a separate question, but, basically your score-handling code could be reduced to a `case` statement and a method to store values in the hash.

Comment: Great Lesson. :) It seems I am newly introduced to `yaml`,although I had already.. :))

Comment: Tin Man, just 1 quick question. I was printing the high score table to the terminal for the user to see after a game is over. Would I be able to use YAML to save the data and then still print it back out with the text-table gem?

Comment: I am getting an error, I am trying to replace the "score: 0" with "@grand_total" and this is what I'm receiving... ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with nil failed
from yahtzee_highscore.rb:29:in `>'

Comment: Also, I am going to refactor the code, just want to get it working first then will refactor the if/else with iteration

Comment: I think I was accessing the hash incorrectly, will post code when I have figured out how to make it work, thanks again Tin Man.

Comment: Once you have it written to your satisfaction, you can post it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com for a code review. Put a comment here referencing it, and we can try refactoring it to help you further.

Comment: Almost satisfactory, but not quite there yet. Thank you for the help thus far Tin Man. I will continue working on it then post to codereview.

Comment: @theTinMan here is a link to my code on codereview... http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28063/how-can-i-refactor-the-yahtzee-program-i-built-in-ruby